# Update all rows in an ASP:LISTVIEW only after conditions

Tags: c#

I am trying to update an asp:ListView once after some conditions on the items are true. The problem is that the update happens on the loop and therefore I end up adding the wrong values.

This is my asp:listview:

```
Item 1     Item 2    Item 3    Item 4     ERROR
john       490        1         0         Message
peter      4          0         0         Message
veronica   2          3         1         Message
Oscar      2          0         0         Message
Caroline   1          0         0         Message
```

The conditions are as follow:

```
1.- I have a total number of 499
2.- The total number of Item 2 (sum of all rows) must match exactly 499
3.- Item 2 cannot be lower than the result of minus Item 3 with Item 4
4.- Once all the conditions are correct, the update must be done globally for all rows in the listview.
```

This is what I am doing:

```
    <asp:label id="lbl_error_outside_view" runat="server"/>
    <asp:ListView ID="gv_browse" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    ...
    </asp:ListView>

    <asp:Button ID="btnupdate" Text="Update All" runat="server" OnClick="btnupdate_Click" />

    protected void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       int total_at = 499;
       int total_global = 0;
       int total_items = 0;

//Get total value for all Item2 column = total_global
foreach (ListViewItem itemRow in this.gv_browse.Items)
{
                    var item2 = itemRow.FindControl("tbx_item2") as TextBox;
                    int item2_int = Convert.ToInt32(item2.Text);
                    total_global = total_global + item2_int;
}

                foreach (ListViewItem itemRow in this.gv_browse.Items)
                {
                    var item1 = itemRow.FindControl("hdn_item1") as HiddenField;
                    var item2 = itemRow.FindControl("tbx_item2") as TextBox;
                    var item3 = itemRow.FindControl("lbl_item3") as Label;
                    var item4 = itemRow.FindControl("lbl_item4") as Label;
                    Label lbl_error = itemRow.FindControl("lbl_error") as Label;

                    int result_item3_4 = (Convert.ToInt32(item3.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(item4.Text));
                    int item2_int = Convert.ToInt32(item2.Text);
                    total_items = total_items + item2_int;

                    if (item2_int < result_item3_4)
                    { 
                       //ERROR, DO NOT UPDATE
                       lbl_error.Text="...";
                    }
                    else if (item2_int >= result_item3_4)
                    {
                       lbl_error.Text = "---"; //Clear error message
                    }
                    if (total_items > total_at)
                    { 
                          //ERROR, DO NOT UPDATE
                       lbl_error_outside_view.Text ="...";
                    }
                    else if (total_global < total_at)
                    {
                          //ERROR, DO NOT UPDATE
                         lbl_error_outside_view.Text="...";
                    }

                }
```

My question is where I put the update line exactly?

```
//Update all in the DB
UpdateData(item1, item2);
```

If I call the UpdateData method in the foreach, I end up updating only the row(s) that are comply with the conditions. What I need is to be able to update all the rows ONLY after verifying that each row is correct? All the conditions work although most probably there is a better way of doing them. Could anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thank you so much.

**UPDATE**

Let me clarify why an ELSE inside the foreach loop does not work:

I populate the listview from the database with several different rows. I added 5 rows as an example. Each row has 3 columns with numerical values, item2, item3 and item4 columns. I have a global number, for this example, I said 499. The sum of item2 in all rows must much exactly this global number, 499. If it doesn't, then the update should not happen (i.e. error shows in the lbl_error_outside_view label). Therefore, here is when the first condition starts: "if total of all rows not equal to global number...".

Now, for the second condition, I need to check each individual row and make sure that Item2 column is not lower than (item3 - item4) columns. If it doesn't, then the update should also not happen (i.e. error shows in the lbl_error label for that particular row). Because I am inside the foreach loop, and because I am checking two different things, sum of total number of item2 rows and then individual rows, I cannot add the else { updateData(item1, item2); } because that will basically just update the row that the condition applies which is not what I need. That is why an else on the loop is not the solution.

All rows should be updated at once ONLY after we know that total number of item2 in all rows is equal to 499 AND each row in item2 is not lower than (item3-item4).

If anyone could share some insides that would be great thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

After several testing I found the best solution to my problem. Basically the solution was in front of my eyes but I was not able to see it until now.

```
foreach (ListViewItem itemRow in this.gv_browse.Items)
{
//run all the conditions here and add ONLY the correct results to a DataTable (if wrong result found, return;)
}
```

then I call the datatable and do the update here.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   //call update method
}
```

In the end, was a pretty simple thing but it took me a while to realize that. I hope this helps someone else that faces the similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for a solution would be considerable in future